# Django - Value error when adding app name in 'INSTALLED APPS'

Tags: python, django

When i add my app name in INSTALLED APPS inside settings.py file, i got the following error and its removed when i erase my app name from settings. What is the problem here?

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors. 
<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000007BFA7BB598>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\postgres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\postgres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in 
inner_run autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "C:\Users\postgres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 250, in raise_last_exception
six.reraise(*_exception)
File "C:\Users\postgres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Users\postgres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\postgres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Users\postgres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
app_config.import_models()
File "C:\Users\postgres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)

return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 781, in get_code
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 741, in source_to_code
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Comment: You have an invalid character somewhere in your app,  try to commit your codes out and keep doing this until it works and then try to figure out where is the error you can use this code to replace the invalid character in your file but you have to do that for every file in your app with open("homework.py", 'r') as infile:
    hw = infile.readlines().replace(chr(0), '')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met almost same problem with you. 
Finally, I found my problem is from the models.py in apps, which is generated by the command 'python manage.py inspectdb > models.py'. 
This models.py is not utf-8 Format. you can open it by notepad++ and change the Format and save it. Then, everything is ok.

Comment: I had the same problem using Sublime 3 as editor. It got solved if I resaved the models.py file in my app folder as 'Save with Encoding :: UTF-8'.